# Kotlin 1.5.20 breaks kapt for dagger/moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, moshi

I have updated kotlin to version `1.5.20` from `1.4.31`. And that caused error during the kapt processing. Kapt fails for dagger & moshi with pretty similar error outputs with metadata/kotlin runtime

For dagger:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ..
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassHeader.<init>(java.lang.Integer, int[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)'
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:992)
    ..
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlinx.metadata.jvm.KotlinClassHeader.<init>(java.lang.Integer, int[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)'
    at dagger.internal.codegen.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:202)
    ..
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol.accept(Symbol.java:1576)
```

For Moshi:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ..
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(int, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)'
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(Java
    ..
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(int, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)'
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlinpoet.classinspector.elements.ElementsClassInspector$containerData$propertyData$3$getterData$1$method$1.<init>(ElementsClassInspector.kt)
    ..
    at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.codegen.MetadataKt.targetType(metadata.kt:208)
```

As a result looks like any dependency which uses `kapt` could fail with a pretty similar error

I expected some version conflict with kotlin runtime/metatada library etc , but haven't found any. What i see in `androidDependencies` task output is that only `1.5.21` is used in runtime, there are also `1.3.71` & `1.4.20` somewhere, but they are updated by dependency solver.
The only cause i can imagine for this that kotlin's **backward compatibility** is broken for some instructions from older versions

We use:

> JVM - `11.0.8`
> Kotlin - `1.5.21`
> Gradle - `6.5`
> Android gradle plugin - `4.1.3` (7.0.0 doesn't help either)
> Dagger - `2.38.1`
> Moshi - `1.12.0`
> Room - `2.3.0`

Regarding `KotlinClassHeader` constructor error, i have noticed that [`kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.3.0`](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.3.0/source-code/kotlinx/metadata/jvm/KotlinClassHeader.kt) dependency provided a new constructor and instantly deprecated it in comparison with [`0.2.0`](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-metadata-jvm/0.2.0/source-code/kotlinx/metadata/jvm/KotlinClassHeader.kt). Could it cause the issue?

This issue is pretty similar: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2717

I appreciate any advice

Answer (score 0):

`kapt.workers.isolation=process` setting causes the issue.

The build was fixed by removing the line.
But i still don't know a root of the problem